# How to correctly use and reference Entity Framework Core in another project?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

So I am building a REST API in .Net core with the following architecture and I'm wondering how to reference Entity Framework Core.

[image]

These are three projects, referencing each other the way it's shown on the image. All the queries are stored in DAL (Data Layer), so this is where I defined DbContext.

But at the same time, I also need to add DbContext to the ConfigureServices on WebAPI Startup (`services.AddDbContext<MyDBContext>();`).

So the main issue is, is that I cannot access DbContext in WebAPI, because WebAPI doesn't directly reference DAL.

I would appreciate very much any tips, suggestions or workarounds, that wouldn't impact the architecture in any major ways.

Comment: I recommend to read about clean architecture https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html and https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture

Comment: The Repository Pattern is a common approach to this.

Comment: What does `services pipeline` do in WebAPi? what are their purposes? It would be great if you share some code of `services pipeline`

Comment: It's the ConfigureServices method.

Comment: In your services and DAL you need to create extension methods that register their dependencies with your DI container.   These extension methods can then be called from your ConfigureServices function.

Comment: Add a project to the top of the hierarchy and set-up the DI container to register all services for all projects. that's the best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the DAL project as reference to the WebApi project, from there you can get access to DbContext, to access the queries of DAl from WebApi you need to used the repository pattern. Here is a nice medium article on how to build a multi layer Asp.Net Core project

https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-nice-multi-layer-net-core-3-api-c68a9ef16368